# I am doing AES-GCM algorithm and I got stuck in one step. Can somebody help me out?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

In the test vectors of AES-GCM, (I have attached the pdf here), in test vectors, 1,2 and 3, the value of `A` is not given.
The link is:
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/114a/4222c53f1a6879f1a77f1bae2fc0f8f55348.pdf

But `len(A) || len(C) = 00000000000000000000000000000080`
`C = 0388dace60b6a392f328c2b971b2fe78`. So `len(C) = 32`, right??
Can somebody help me, how to get the value of `A` and its length.
I am doing this algorithm, AES-GCM. Can somebody help me to solve this issue??

Answer (score 2):

The GCM paper, in section 2.2 says

> The  function  len() returns a  64-bit  string  containing  the  nonnegative  integer  describing the  num­ber  of  bits  in  its  argument,  with  the  least  significant  bit  on  the  right.

The `C` value in test case 2 is 32 hex characters, or 16 bytes, or 128 (0x80) bits.

`len(C)` produces as 64-bit value, which in big-endian hexadecimal is `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80`.  The upper half of the 128-bit value is `len(A)`.  It's all zeros, so `len(A)` is zero, which matches `A` being absent.  This is corroborated by the intro text to the test vectors section:

> All  values  are  in  hexadecimal,  and  **a  zero-length  variable  is  indicated  by  the  absence of  any  hex  digits**.

(emphasis mine).

Comment: So if A=0, what will be the length of A. Is A = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00??

Comment: @Darsana A is an octet string, expressed in that document as hex, so ‘0’ isn’t valid. If it is empty, the length is zero. If it is ‘00’ the length is eight (bits), or ‘00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08’ in 64-bit big endian.